# Can't see some objects' internals in Qt Creator's Locals and Expressions debug window

Tags: debugging, qt, qt-creator, watch

I'd like to see the member variables of objects whilst debugging in Qt Creator. I can see all of the internals of my own objects, but I can't see the members of a `QGraphicsView`, for example.

[image: qt locals and expressions]

I'm also curious to know why it says `<unavailable synchronous data>` for `std::map`. Here's a small example of that:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::map<int, std::string> someMap;
    someMap.insert(std::make_pair(1, "cats"));
    someMap.insert(std::make_pair(2, "dogs"));
    someMap.insert(std::make_pair(3, "vlag"));
    return 0;
}
```

My build settings are as follows:

[image: qt build settings]
[image: qt creator version]

Answer (score 1):

See my answer to the question "[Can I customize autoexp.dat to enable visualization of a QT QDomNode in Visual Studio 2010 Debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796361/can-i-customize-autoexp-dat-to-enable-visualization-of-a-qt-qdomnode-in-visual-s/5988529#5988529)". Qt uses the pimpl ideom to hide the private data of its classes and to provide binary compatibility within a major version.

Comment: How do I use this with Qt Creator? From a quick search, it seems that autoexp.dat is a Visual Studio file.

Comment: The problem is not the visualization code in the debugger (i.e. autoexp.dat with Visual Studio) but the fact that the debugger does not see the definition of the private parts. See e.g. http://qt-project.org/wiki/Dpointer or do a web search for Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE.

Comment: So there is no way to show the private data? That seems a bit odd.

Comment: You can see them if the compiler sees the definitions, e.g. if you step into one of the methods. Or you can write a special visualizer for some types (as fas as I know you can use python for that). Or you can use a hacky way by including (for testing purposes only) the private header file in the file where you want to watch some variable.

Comment: Ok, stepping into one of the object's methods is a possibility, not very convenient though. May as well use `qDebug()`. It seems odd that there isn't already a visualiser for the standard Qt types.